# Nested table formatting with simple_form, nested_form and twitter-bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, nested-forms, simple-form

**Update:** *I updated this after doing some digging and realizing that this might be twitter-bootstrap causing the problem.*

Here is a rough version of my nested form:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @user, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :name_first %>
    <%= f.input :name_last %>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Active</th>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                  <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <%= f.simple_fields_for :roles, :wrapper_tag => :tr do |role_form| %>
                    <td><%= role_form.hidden_field :id %><%= role_form.input :active, :label => false, :wrapper => false %></td>
                    <td><%= role_form.association :company, :label => false, :wrapper => false %></td>
                    <td><%= role_form.input :role, :label => false, :collection => [ "Guest", "User", "Inspector", "Owner"], :wrapper => false %></td>
                    <td><%= role_form.link_to_remove "Delete", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
                    </td>
                  <% end %> 
              </tbody>
            </table>
               <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Role", :roles %></p>
        </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

When it's rendered the fields in the table rows are indented the same as the parent form via the `{ :class => 'form-horizontal' }`.  I just want the fields with no wrapper divs etc. and can't seem to figure it out.  I thought the `:wrapper => false` was the ticket but no luck so far.

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out on my own.  You have to move the form style (form-horizontal) into a div just around the non-nested fields:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :name_first %>
    <%= f.input :name_last %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :mobile %>

    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="tubbable">...
```

Comment: Can you post your complete final solution, because i getting problems to add the nested_form part into the table, and it looks that you getting working. I will appreciated.

Comment: I ended up walking away from this view - if I recall the div around the inputs was the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a table (as in your initial example) to do the layout, I've patched the nested_form gem here https://github.com/ritchiey/nested_form to allow that.

To specify that you want the new fields appended at the bottom of the tbody and wrapped in a tr, replace your current link_to_add call with:

```
<%= f.link_to_add "Add a Role", :roles, :container =>'tbody', :fields_element=>'tr'%>
```

Note: the :container param is a CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:wrapper => false` to the simple_nested_form_for call.
The problem is, that :wrapper => false in simple_fields_for gets overwritten by the default :wrapper => nil in the simple_form_for configuration.

See this link for a setup:
[How To: Render nested fields inside a table](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/How-To%3a-Render-nested-fields-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to remove the div wrapper from an input field, use `f.input_field` instead of `f.input`:

```
= f.input_field :email, label: false, placeholder: 'email'
```