# How do I change simple_fields_for's HTML tag in <div class="fields"> from div to something else?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, nested-forms

I'm using simple_nested_form (simple_form, nested_form), twitter-bootstrap and I'd like to use `<tr class="fields">` to wrap the input fields of a child record, to have one record in one table row and all child records below each other in a table. I tried this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :classification_classes, wrapper_tag: 'tr', wrapper: :in_line do |ccf| %>
```

But unfortunately the `wrapper_tag: 'tr'` did not changed anything. I'm using a custom wrapper `in_line` to have the fields without label and with span tag instead of div, but there is no control for the most outermost `<div class="fields">` which destroys the HTML structure of the table.

I know about https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/How-To%3a-Render-nested-fields-inside-a-table , but there is about a solution without simple_form, what lacks of the nice rendering of validation errors beside the fields.

There is also a question [Nested table formatting with simple_form, nested_form and twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762374/nested-table-formatting-with-simple-form-nested-form-and-twitter-bootstrap) but it doesn't work as described there.

Any suggestions?